# How to scroll fix elements using Iscroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

I am using iscroll in my project.I want to scroll 3 item at one time when user scroll 
id it possible using iscroll library ?I already try to scrollTo but it will not work ?

Here is my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/amnishyadav/dWYJS/

```
var isScrolling = false;
myScroll = new iScroll('headerWrapper',{
    snap: 'li',
    hScrollbar: false,
    vScrollbar: false,
    momentum: true,
    vScroll: false,
    onScrollMove : function(e){
        // clearHeaderInterval();
        // myScroll.scrollTo(50, 0);
        // myScroll.refresh();

        console.log('onScrollMove===============>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
        isScrolling = true;

        // here get the device type and version
        if(deviceType() == 'android'){
            var deviceVersion = device.version;

            console.log(" deviceType is ===>>"+deviceVersion);
            if(deviceVersion=='4.1' || deviceVersion=='4.1.1'|| deviceVersion=='4.1.2'){
                console.log("android version is ===>>"+deviceVersion);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    myScroll.refresh();
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
        // setTimeout(function(){myScroll.refresh();},0);
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here, do you want to have 3 different scrollable areas that can each be scrolled separately from each other? If so then you can just initiate the scroll event on each area you want to scroll.

```
<div id="firstScroller">
    <div class="scroller">
    <!-- content here -->
    </div>
</div>

<div id="secondScroller">
    <div class="scroller">
    <!-- content here -->
    </div>
</div>

<div id="thirdScroller">
    <div class="scroller">
    <!-- content here -->
    </div>
</div>


function loaded() {
    setTimeout(function () {
         firstScroller = new iScroll('firstScroller', {
            hScrollbar: false,
            vScrollbar: false,
            hScroll: false
        });
        secondScroller = new iScroll('secondScroller', {
            hScrollbar: false,
            vScrollbar: false,
            hScroll: false
        });
        thirdScroller = new iScroll('thirdScroller', {
            hScrollbar: false,
            vScrollbar: false,
            hScroll: false
        });
    }, 100);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

If that's not what you're after then if you could update your question I might be able to help